# JSON.stringify not serializing Extended class props

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, stringify

I have an issue stringifying JavaScript extended class. First, I create MyError class as extension of Error and then try JSON.stringify on a new instance of MyError.

I expect to see .message property of the inherited (Error) class, but stringify only serializes direct attributes of MyError class. See code and output below.

Is there a way to tell stringify to include Error.message? Or an easy workaround to achieve this?

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message, hint = "") {
    super(message);
    this.message = message; // attempt to trick .stringify
    this.hint = hint;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(new MyError("hello world");));
```

Actual output: `{"hint":""}`

Desired output: `{"message":"hello world","hint":""}`

Comment: Hint: [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks for hint, I have tried playing with toJSON but I need to either manually or by reflection inspect the super object in order to return what needs to be done and there is quite a lot of options to cover (e.g. if the key is array or prop or etc) so feels like an overkill... As a newbie to JavaScript I was hoping for something simpler.